# Failed to open stream No such file or directory

Tags: php, compiler-errors

I'm using the new code what people have been telling me to use. I just cant figure out why the PHP is not being accessed. ok, the php are stored on a server else where and the folder structure is - public/work/return.php.

So far I have set my code as

```
  <?php
  include_once("pdo_mysql.php"); 
  pdo_connect("***", "***", "***");
  pdo_select_db("***");
```

but I keep getting the error of

```
include_once(pdo_mysql.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please complete your question.

Comment: why don't you use any quotes in your code?

Comment: What you posted isn't valid PHP. And I don't see any mention of `pdo_mysql.php` in your code -- is it in `Return.php`?

Comment: What do you not understand? "No such file or directory" is quite self-explanatory.

Comment: is there a `pdo_mysql.php` file in the same directory of your code?

Comment: @ Sverri M. Olsen, Thanks for your input and time.. but I have typed the correct path name for it to display. I might of just left something out..

Comment: @Alireza Fallah No there is not, I thought just changing the old code from 'mysql_' to 'pdo_' would just work.

Comment: so thats because you get this error !!!

Comment: @ Alireza Fallah, ok guess I need to research into pdo_mysql.php

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0):

Now you have to use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] to access file path

Answer (score 0):

For including files you can use : `include_once __DIR__ . '/file/to/path'`

Similar : `include_once __DIR__ ."/pdo_mysql.php";`